# RSA Javascript encryption and Golang decryption

Tags: javascript, go, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a scenario where I need to use **RSA public key encryption standard** with **JavaScript** and **Golang**. 
I need to encrypt data in JavaScript using public key and decrypt the same in Golang using the private key.
I tried using **PKCS#1(travst library for JavaScript and crypto/rsa for Golang)**, but failed in decryption. Can anyone suggest solutions for this?

**I tried all possible solutions and researched many documents, but still I couldn't find a proper method. If I do encrypt and decrypt within golang, its working fine. But there is some integration problem between javascript and golang. I am not sure about the padding methodology used in javasript.**

This is my golang code to decrypt:

```
func Decrypt(encryptedData, label []byte) (decryptedData []byte) {
var err error
var block *pem.Block
var private_key *rsa.PrivateKey

if block, _ = pem.Decode([]byte(privatKeyData)); block == nil || block.Type != "RSA PRIVATE KEY" { //privatKeyData is in string format
    log.Fatal("No valid PEM data found")
}

//Read Private Key
if private_key, err = x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Private key can't be decoded: %s", err)
}

//Decrypt
if decrypted, err = rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, private_key, encryptedData); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
}
return
}
```

Comment: can you post the error received? or show us the decryption result.

Comment: @SimoEndre Error: crypto/rsa: decryption error (i just received this error)

Comment: I tried decoding the encrypted data from base64 format and decrypted it, but still received the same error

Comment: Share your code, to have an idea on the issue.

Comment: Assume you mean [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) library?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to encrypt in javascript and decrypt in Go. Using the library you refer to, [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt):

Create public & private key pair:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout > pub.pem
```

Encryption in javascript:

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey($('#pubkey').val());

var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt($('#message').val());

$.post("/decrypt", encrypted, function(response) {
    $("#decrypted").val(response);
});
```

Decryption in Go:

```
func handleDecrypt(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    encrypted, err := ioutil.ReadAll(decoder)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    data, err := rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, encrypted)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "decrypt error", http.StatusBadRequest)
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, string(data))
}
```

Update: the privateKey variable is a *rsa.PrivateKey derived from the private key file created by openssl, in this case the "key.pem" file. A pem file is a Base64 encoded DER certificate, eg, -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- show a private key in PEM format. Go standard library provides the [x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey()](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParsePKCS1PrivateKey) method to parse a pem encoded key from a byte slice.

So loading the key into Go might look something like this:

```
keyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("path/to/key.pem")
if err != nil { ... }

privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(keyBytes)
if err != nil { ... }
```

Comment: Where did the "privateKey" variable come from?

Answer (score 3):

1：You can encrypt cleartext in javascript reference from.

> https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey($('#pubkey').val());
var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt($('#input').val());
```

2：Be aware of that the jsencrypt has already done encrypt and base64encode.

Be aware of that  jsencrypt use PKCS1 not OAEP

3: Base64decode in golang and decrypt message from step 1.

```
var encrypted := 'change this to the encrypted text your js sent'
privateKey,_ = ioutil.ReadFile("private.pem")
cipherText,_ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encrypted)
originText,_ :=RsaDecrypt([]byte(cipherText))
```

decrypt function

```
func RsaDecrypt(cipherText []byte) ([]byte, error) {
        block, _ := pem.Decode(privateKey)
        if block == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("private key error!")
        }
        priv, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        return rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, priv, cipherText)
    }
```

now you get the encrypted text `originText`
reference from

> https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000002505932

4: Further more, you can generate key pair in go

```
func GenRsaKey(bits int) error {
    privateKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bits)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    derStream := x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(privateKey)
    block := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "privete key",
        Bytes: derStream,
    }
    file, err := os.Create("private.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = pem.Encode(file, block)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    publicKey := &privateKey.PublicKey
    derPkix, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    block = &pem.Block{
        Type:  "public key",
        Bytes: derPkix,
    }
    file, err = os.Create("public.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = pem.Encode(file, block)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: From the very begining,I get error crypto/rsa: decryption error. but this does not inform me anything,so I try the corresponding code in python,it raisees error ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length,then I guess maybe is the base64decoding issue ,then I google it ,I find in other programme language such java or node.js ,it always do base64decoding.